# Compare 2 csv files using python pandas and save the output in a list or set

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare 2 csv files and output the changes in a list or set using python pandas without iteration.

### file1.csv

- Alex
- Johnny
- Mark
- Steve
- Raul

### file2.csv

- Alex
- Mark

I want the output to be something like
p.s: Csv files contain the names as rows (Every row 1 name)

difference = [ Johnny, Steve, Raul] or {'Johnny','Steve','Raul'}

Comment: are the names unique ? if so you could use set difference from numpy for instance

Comment: Yes they are unique but can you help me in code ? The row number is a bit large around 50k rows

Answer (score 1):

The numpy setdiff1d() function is used to find the set difference of two arrays.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file1 = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\datasets\file1.csv' #path to file1
file2 = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\datasets\file2.csv' #path to file2
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1) #convert csv to dataframe
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2) #convert csv to dataframe
diff = np.setdiff1d(df1, df2, assume_unique=False)
```